# Photo sent from warranty repairs is much better quality than what the printer actually prints

Tags: printing, printer, photos

I sent my printer to repairs, because it wasn't printing color properly. I had tried doing printer head cleaning before that multiple times, but every time less color came out. This is not the first time that I've had to send my printer to repairs because of this issue. This time they also sent me a little showcase photo. It looked absolutely amazing, with no color deformations or stripes and the quality was amazing. I had never seen  such a high quality photo come out of this printer, so I decided to print something myself. But something just isn't right. To start of the photo has stripes. I tried to fix it with printer head alignment, but it only got a little better. Secondly the colours look much more flushed down and desaturated. How are they acheiving this quality and why does the printer have problems again? Has anyone else eperienced this? The printer is an EPSON L3150.

Comment: What were the print quality settings? What type of paper did you use? What ink (Epson or third-party)? Have you performed **power** cleaning, https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd5/cpd57083/source/printers/source/ink_functions/concepts/power_cleaning.html ? BTW, I do find EcoTank printers require cleaning if inactive for a long time, with a wait required to remove air from lines, but they do a *very* fine job.

Comment: IIRC there's a special deep clean - which I end up needing if I use it less than once a month. Mine's a handmedown that gets fed random ink so I've no idea how well it can print but...

Comment: This is a $250USD printer.  How many times is it worth fixing?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I used the highest quality settings and thick paper. The ink was the original that came with the printer. I haven't done power cleaning, because I'm scared it will mess up the colors again.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Well the warranty is still active so I guess I'll take it to repairs as long as it doesn't expire.

Comment: 1. *Thick* paper is not necessarily good -- or bad. Ink-jet paper is *coated* specifically to keep ink in its place. Photo ink-jet paper, in particular, has a coating to absorb ink in a controlled manner, but keep it within microns of where the drop landed. 2. The EcoTank printers are robustly made, unlike many with cartridges, and *is* worth maintaining...  but one must follow the directions, including deep cleaning, **if needed**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many variables in getting a good quality print. Paper quality is one of the things. Thicker paper will work better, and if you specify the correct thickness in the printer dialog, the printer will use more ink to get that higher quality print.

Other settings in the printer dialog, such as eco vs quality will also matter.

In addition, photo paper, a special paper will produce real photo quality prints if you use that paper and specify this as the quality too. (high quality means more ink usage means higher costs)

Lastly, in programs like photoshop, you can also specify if the program should tell the printer what to print, or let the printer decide. With more basic programs, this often is missing and that means your OS will tell the printer what to print. This is often using the incorrect color profile, which will make the colors less accurate.

And a side note, The colors on screen, if the screen is not accurate enough can also skewer the results. You should not compare the image you printed with what you see on the screen. Instead, take a photo of what you see in real life with correct settings, verify on your monitor that it at least looks good enough (not too dark, and not too bright) and print that, then compare it with the real thing.